# if exist column value in sql

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables

I want to select all record from the below query, if the [@myTable].MessageId
value does not exists consider it 0, in the join.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
        (
          MessageId BIGINT ,
          RecieverId VARCHAR(100)
        )



    INSERT  INTO @myTable
            ( MessageId ,
              RecieverId

            )
            SELECT  MAX(MessageID) ,
                    ReceiverID
            FROM    dbo.CM_MessageStatus
            WHERE   ReceiverID IN ( SELECT  *
                                    FROM    string_split(@UserID, ',') )
                    AND DeliveredDate IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY ReceiverID

SELECT  COUNT(CM_MessageStatus.MessageID) AS MessageID ,
        dbo.CM_MessageStatus.ReceiverID
FROM    dbo.CM_MessageStatus
        LEFT   JOIN @myTable ON [@myTable].RecieverId = CM_MessageStatus.ReceiverID
                                AND CM_MessageStatus.MessageID > [@myTable].MessageId
WHERE   --DeliveredDate IS NULL AND
```

--if [@myTable].MessageId does not exists consider it 0

```
    CM_MessageStatus.MessageID > [@myTable].MessageId
    AND ReceiverID IN ( SELECT  *
                        FROM    string_split(@UserID, ',') )
GROUP BY dbo.CM_MessageStatus.ReceiverID
```

Note: I want to check if [@myTable].MessageId does not exists consider it 0

[image]

Comment: Hello Bilal, I read your question, but I don't understand what is your issue exactly, do you mean `MessageId = NULL` then replace _NULL_ with 0?

Comment: if [@myTable].MessageId does not exists consider it 0, please see the picture

Comment: Still not clear, mybe you mean if there is no data in your table then the result must be like _0 rows_?

Answer (score 0):

```
        INSERT  INTO @myTable
        ( MessageId ,
          RecieverId

        )
        SELECT  MAX(MessageID) ,
                ReceiverID
        FROM    dbo.CM_MessageStatus
        WHERE   ReceiverID IN ( SELECT  *
                                FROM    string_split(@UserID, ',') )
                AND DeliveredDate IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY ReceiverID

     IF @@ROWCOUNT= 0 
         insert into @myTable values(0,0)
         select * from @mytable
     ELSE 
         select * from @myTable
```

Comment: I got what you are saying. In this case, I have edited the above query, where i have included a check for the Rowcount as below. If Rowcount = 0, then have 0 inserted in your table variable, else return the table row. Hope this helps!